# UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell returning empty always even though shows as selected

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am using a UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell. I am able to select the cells inside the UICollectionView. But when i try to get the UICollectionView or selected cells, the result is always null.I have been stuck on this for a long time. i included my code below for your reference.

```
class WeekDaysSelCell: UITableViewCell,UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var weekdays = ["S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S"]

    var weekdaysSelected = [String]()

    @IBOutlet var weeklyDaysColView: UICollectionView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.weeklyDaysColView.delegate = self
        self.weeklyDaysColView.dataSource = self
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 7
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell : WeekDaysCollCell = weeklyDaysColView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "weekday", for: indexPath) as! WeekDaysCollCell

        cell.weekDayLabel.text = weekdays[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let cell : WeekDaysCollCell = self.weeklyDaysColView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! WeekDaysCollCell
        if (cell.backgroundColor == UIColor.gray) {
            cell.backgroundColor  = UIColor.clear
            weekdaysSelected.removeAll { $0 == String(indexPath.row)}
            //print("Removed from weekdaysSelected:", indexPath.row)
        } else {

            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
            cell.isSelected = true
            //weeklyDaysColView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: [])
            weekdaysSelected.append(String(indexPath.row))
            //print("Added to weekdaysSelected:", indexPath.row)
        }
    }
}

// Trying to get the collection view from inside a willMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?) method. 

    override func willMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?) {
            super.willMove(toParent: parent)
            if parent == nil
            {

                if let delegate = self.delegate {
                print("Inside If condition")

                // Code that i use to get the cell 
                let cell3 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell3") as! WeekDaysSelCell

                    print(cell3.weekdaysSelected)

                    print(cell3.weeklyDaysColView.indexPathsForSelectedItems)

                    // Trying to pass selected cells
                    //delegate.repeatCustomSelection(selectedIdx: String(lastSelection.row),repeatCustomSel: repeatCustomSelection)
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What yo want when ever user selected any collectionviewCell, indexPath of that cell or value of that model?

Comment: IndexPath of the cell to find out if the cell has been selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get a reusable cell in `willMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?)` , this is not going to return you a expected cell.

You need to get the cell , using a indexPath .

`func cellForRow(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell?`

Comment: Sorry.. I am a newbie with swift. How can i get the indexpath inside willMove method? The reason i am calling the collection view from inside willMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?) is to pass the selected cells back to the parent view controller. I updated the code to include the willMove method

Comment: I stored the indexPath using another variable var weekDayCellIndexPath : IndexPath! and stored the indexPath from inside override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) and this is working. Please let me know if this is a correct approach or is there any other better way of obtaining the indexpath inside willMove method

Comment: I think you need a model object , pass the model object to the child view control. In didselect of collection view or table view keep updating it,that way you don’t need anthing specific to implement in willlMovetoparent.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into the approach which is aside from my earlier question. Your answer helped me find out the issue. I will accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

@andyPaul, is right you are generating the new cell in willMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?). Instead of that you have to pass the indexpath pf collection view when ever user selected any cell to your controller from the tableView Cell Class.

Now What is TypeAlias you can read from this link about type alias:- https://www.programiz.com/swift-programming/typealias

1. Create the typeAlias on above of your tableViewCell Class like this:-

   ```
   typealias closureBlock = (_ isCapture : AnyObject?) ->()

    class tableViewCellClass: UITableViewCell {

     var callBack: closureBlock?

     override func awakeFromNib() {
         super.awakeFromNib()
         // Initialization code
     }
   ```
2. Just Go to CollectionView didSelectItemAt Method and use this code after your coding

   ```
     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

     let cell : WeekDaysCollCell = self.weeklyDaysColView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! WeekDaysCollCell
     if (cell.backgroundColor == UIColor.gray) {
         cell.backgroundColor  = UIColor.clear
         weekdaysSelected.removeAll { $0 == String(indexPath.row)}
         //print("Removed from weekdaysSelected:", indexPath.row)
     } else {

         cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
         cell.isSelected = true
         //weeklyDaysColView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: [])
         weekdaysSelected.append(String(indexPath.row))
         //print("Added to weekdaysSelected:", indexPath.row)
      }

        guard let callBackClosure = self.callBack else {
            return
        }
        callBackClosure(indexPath as AnyObject)
        // You can pass any value here either indexpath or Array.
      }                  
   }
   ```
3. Now you have to initialise this closure so that it can check whether in which controller it will return the value when you assign the value from CollectionView **didSelectItemAt** Method.
4. Go to your **ViewController** Class where you have added the tableview and their datasources.

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        //You have to pass your tableview Cell Instance here and their reuse Identifier
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableViewCellClass", for: indexPath) as! tableViewCellClass

        cell.callBack = { [weak self] (selectedIndexPath) -> ()in
         // You will get the current selected index path of collection view here, Whenever you pass any index path from collectionView did SelectItem Method.
           print(selectedIndexPath)
       }
       return cell
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for looking into my issue. I will try this method and post my comments. For now Andy's solution solved my problem.